# What is the proper usage of この上なく / この上ない?

Tags: politeness

I have encountered the structure ことこの上ない with the explanation that it is used as

Adjectiveな + ことこの上ない
Adjectiveい + ことこの上ない

with the meaning of "nothing is more 'adjective'". For example "嫌なことこのうえない", "nothing is more annoying."

I have also found the form この上なく with the example "この上なく幸せだ".

My questions are

1. Are these forms equivalent? Is there a difference in formality level or something like that?
2. I have seen examples of the first form that suppresses the こと. Is this because it is implicit　こと is there?
3. Finally, I have seen an example where the form is used "このうえないものだ". Could I say "このうえなかった"? Or is このうえない a set form?

Comment: Someone else may answer more in detail, but there is a difference between ～ない幸せ and ～なく幸せ, since in the former you are modifying the noun 幸せ (and it may be the subject), but in the latter the subject is implied to be 私. Can you give examples of 2, where you suppress こと? With 3, please provide context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The construction ことこの上ない has probably the only meaning of "nothing is more 'adjective'. For example "嫌なことこのうえない", "nothing is more annoying."

> 1. Adjectiveな + ことこのうえない　⇒　きれいなことこのうえない and だめなことこのうえない
> 2. Adjectiveい + ことこのうえない　⇒　やさしいことこのうえない and きたないことこのうえない

You have also found the form 'このうえなく+adjective', with the example "この上なく幸せだ".

> 3. このうえなく+adjective　⇒　このうえなくうつくしい and このうえなくきらいだ

Basically the above two constructions, having こと, and the third one are equivalent in meaning, but, of course, different in the position of adjective. Let's have a look at other expressions, not only grammatical but also a little informal, and consider this construction more deeply.

- このうえない平和と調和を感じさせる。
- 彼の仕事ぶりには、このうえない安心感がある。
- このうえなくいい天気でした。
- 空はこのうえないぐらいの青空だ。
- つかまえにくい**こと**、このうえない。
- とにかく風通しがいい**こと**、このうえないのだ。
- 天気のいい**こと**、このうえない。
- 彼の理解がはやい**こと**、このうえなくまさっている。
- その古い橋を渡る危険な**こと**、このうえない。
- その危険、このうえない。
- この賞を受賞した名誉(meiyo)、このうえない。
- この受賞(jyusho)、このうえない名誉だ。
- 彼女の活躍（katsuyaku）、このうえなくすばらしい。

I have read through these sentences and, strangely enough, I have rewritten one of the above sentences like this「天気のいいこと、このうえない。」. I omitted（、）from the sentences intentionally, but now I have discovered myself that ことこのうえない should be understood separately as [こと] and [このうえない]. Yes, some of them have the construction like this: [noun phrase] + このうえない. And among many noun phrases, こと is one of them.

The last question must be answered. 'I have seen an example where the form is used "このうえないものだ". Could I say "このうえなかった"? Or is このうえない a set form?'

- このうえないものだ
- ことこのうえないものだ
- このうえなかった
- ことこのうえなかった

Last of all, reflecting on the use of このうえない or このうえなく in my own writing, I have often used this expression in the superlative meaning rather than comparative, because I have avoided expressions such as 最高の～ or 最も～. I am now a little tired with one-hour brainstorming, so I am going to stop here.